# Zigbee Device from Cloud

Tags: http, networking, udp, cloud, zigbee

I have a legacy setup that utilizes a Zigbee Controller within a LAN. We have an application that communicates with that controller over UDP to send commands to Zigbee devices.

We'd like to be able to send commands from a cloud-based server to a controller running within a LAN without forwarding a port on the firewall.

So ultimately: Our app in cloud => (something) => Local Firewall => LAN => (something) => Zigbee Controller

I'm wondering what the best (somethings) are to accomplish this. In the end, I want to take our current UDP messages that are being sent on (some) port, translate them to packets that can be sent to a device inside a LAN on port 80 which then re-sends them over the proper UDP port. I'm assuming this is somehow possible, but I'm not sure of the right approach / device.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You may try "hole punching" over UDP. The basic idea is to let the client (your ZigBee controller) send a periodic message to the cloud over UDP to maintain an active connection. Your cloud server will be able to send messages to the controller, without port forwarding and, because of UDP, without having to maintain an active session like it does over TCP.